# How can I preconfigure wireless?

Tags: wireless

I want to be able to enter wireless details such as SSID and password onto the OS and have the Pi boot up for the first time and connect to an access point, without having to first configure it via an ethernet connection. How can I do that?

Apart from the Pi I only have access to Mac hardware.

Comment: You can configure it to a extent from editing files on the card - which OS are you using on the Pi (and the computer you are configuring it from)?

Comment: I'm using Raspbian for the most part. I also don't have access to any other Linux clients than the Pi.

Comment: Either use the first pi as your editing platform, or probably more efficiently use a live linux image in a virtual machine on the mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Raspbian then the easiest way is by using wpa_supplicant.

First make sure wpa_supplicant is managing your WLAN (I'm assuming it's wlan0 here) by editing `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Then input your WiFi details in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
network={
    ssid="Your SSID here"
    psk="Your password here"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Comment: BEWARE This may not work with the latest Raspbian, which uses `dhcpcd`

Comment: @Milliways I'm using this on Raspbian Jessie with `dhcpcd` disabled.

Comment: In which case it probably won't work for the questioner, who is unlikely to be using a prerelease.

Comment: @Milliways this exact configuration is on my Raspbian Wheezy as well. I haven't touched `dhcpcd` there.

Comment: I am not saying this can't be made to work. Are you using the May 2105 issue of Raspbian? If not have you installed `raspberrypi-net-mods`? If not your installation is unlikely to be representative of most new users asking questions here.

Comment: @Milliways just for the sake of argument I've flashed Raspbian image from May 2015: `2015-05-05-raspbian-wheezy.img`. The ONLY changed I've made is that I added the `network` section to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.  `/etc/network/interfaces` was already correct by default. Then I plugged in a WiFi dongle and booted the Pi. And it works. I don't know what else I need to do to convince you.

Comment: This discussion is not helping the original questioner. The default `/etc/network/interfaces` contains auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: @Milliways what are you trying to prove? So default `/etc/network/interfaces` is correct and doesn't need to be modified. Is that the issue? You said my solution is not going to work on stock Raspbian from May 2015 because of `dhcpcd`, but it does work.

Comment: Even if editing interfaces and wpa_supplicant.conf works it's only perhaps half the answer. How do I edit? From what, into what? Is this what's called preseeding?

Comment: @yusf if you're on Linux, you just plug the SD card in and edit those files on the root partition. On Windows or Mac that is a bit more challenging since don't natively support ext file systems.
All you have to do is add your network details as in the answer to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file.

Comment: @GeorgeSapkin Seems like the closest solution right now, but requires additional steps for enabling Ext support in OS X. Isn't there a way of passing the info along to the Ext partition from the FAT boot partition?

Answer (score 1):

This should actually work pretty much out of the box. If you are able to mount an ext4 partition (which as far as I understand [should be feasible with Mac OS](http://osxdaily.com/2014/03/20/mount-ext-linux-file-system-mac/)) you can mount the second partition of the sd card (not the one labeled boot, but the other one with the root file system) and edit `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` to your needs.

Assuming your AP is protected with WPA/WPA2 you will have to add the password to the `wpa_supplicant.conf`. Easiest way is by doing following as root:

```
wpa_passphrase "AP-name" "password" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

That's the only thing you should need to change. Having a compatible USB wifi adapter it shouldn't require anything else. This is tested on Raspbian Jessie and Jessie lite as of jan 2016.